# C# Windows Store WebView get user-agent

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Is there a way to extract the user-agent string that the WebView control uses?  If so, I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can give me a method to do so.  Using the following does not seem to work:

```
        var userAgent = new StringBuilder(256);
        int length = 0;
        UrlMkGetSessionOption(UrlMonOptionUserAgent, userAgent, userAgent.Capacity - 1, ref length, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I take that back, using UrlMkGetSessionOption as mentioned in the code above does work.

Comment: My comment grew too large, so added as an answer that expands on yours. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use this method, adapted from a method given for windows phone originally. It gives the correct result, and gets it straight from a real instance of a WebView object, so gives me more confidence in it having the correct value.

```
    private static string s_userAgent = null;

    // Get the default UserAgent which webviews use on this platform.
    public async Task<string> GetUserAgent()
    {
        if (s_userAgent == null)
        {
            const string Html = @"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"">
                                <html>
                                <head>
                                    <script language=""javascript"" type=""text/javascript"">
                                        function notifyUA() { window.external.notify(navigator.userAgent); } 
                                    </script>
                                </head>
                                <body onload=""notifyUA();""></body>
                                </html>";

            SemaphoreSlim signal_done = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

            var wv = new WebView();
            wv.ScriptNotify += (sender, args) =>
            {
                s_userAgent = args.Value;
                // set signal, to show we've done
                signal_done.Release();
            };
            wv.NavigateToString(Html);

            // wait for signal 
            await signal_done.WaitAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine("GetUserAgent() called. User agent from WebView: \n{0}", s_userAgent);
        }

        return s_userAgent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This started as a comment but became too long. To expand on his (@Rexfelis) own answer:

I've found that there can be a difference in what `UrlMkGetSessionOption` returns depending on where you are in the application lifecycle and if a `WebView` has been initialized yet in a XAML view.

If you call it before component initialization, it will be missing `WebView/3.0` (at least in Windows 10); after initialization it will have that text and results in the same string as the answer by @SimonTillson.

If you need to know the right user agent before component initialization, you have to new up a `WebView` and navigate before querying `UrlMkGetSessionOption`; e.g. `var wv = new WebView(); wv.NavigateToString(...);`. It seems that the user agent is modified on first navigation to include `WebView/3.0`.